# Postulates of general relativity

Tags: general-relativity

Special relativity derives from two postulates:

1. Invariance of $c$
2. Principle of relativity

The same axiomatic procedure is possible for quantum mechanics. Now, does exist a set of axioms for general relativity in order the derive the theory in a straightforward way? I would say that one of them is the "equivalence principle" and the others?

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259065/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219681/50583

Comment: I would add the [clock postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_hypothesis) (doesn't seem necessary for SR, but looks necessary for GR else you cannot move on from the equivalence principle).

Comment: Here, I must simply point out a few fabulous videos on YouTube (playlist can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkYpif7kNGM&list=PLDB15F7E29A5F0426&index=6)). (I may make an answer later summarizing the points made.)

Answer (score -2):

Einstein's general relativity has no postulates:

https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-postulates-of-General-Relativity 
 What are the postulates of General Relativity? Alexander Poltorak, Adjunct Professor of Physics at the CCNY:

> In 2005 I started writing a paper, “The Four Cornerstones of General Relativity on which it doesn’t Rest.” Unfortunately, I never had a chance to finish it. The idea behind that unfinished article was this: there are four principles that are often described as “postulates” of General Relativity:
>
> 1. Principle of general relativity
> 2. Principle of general covariance
> 3. Equivalence principle
> 4. Mach principle
>
> The truth is, however, that General Relativity is not really based on any of these “postulates” although, without a doubt, they played important heuristic roles in the development of the theory.

Sometimes Einsteinians absurdly call the final equations of general relativity "postulates":

http://math.stanford.edu/~schoen/trieste2012/lecture_3.pdf

> Postulates of General Relativity 
>   Postulate 1: A spacetime (M^4, g) is a Riemannian 4-manifold M^4 with a Lorentzian metric g. 
>   Postulate 2: A test mass beginning at rest moves along a timelike geodesic. (Geodesic equation) ... 
>   Postulate 3: Einstein equation is satisfied. (Einstein equation) ..."

Special relativity is deductive (even though a false postulate and an invalid argument spoiled it from the very beginning) but general relativity is an empirical model, analogous to the empirical models defined here:

http://collum.chem.cornell.edu/documents/Intro_Curve_Fitting.pdf

> The objective of curve fitting is to theoretically describe experimental data with a model (function or equation) and to find the parameters associated with this model. Models of primary importance to us are mechanistic models. Mechanistic models are specifically formulated to provide insight into a chemical, biological, or physical process that is thought to govern the phenomenon under study. Parameters derived from mechanistic models are quantitative estimates of real system properties (rate constants, dissociation constants, catalytic velocities etc.). It is important to distinguish mechanistic models from empirical models that are mathematical functions formulated to fit a particular curve but whose parameters do not necessarily correspond to a biological, chemical or physical property."

Comment: What are the false postulate and invalid argument you refer to?

Comment: If the fact that the rate of a clock doesn't depend on its acceleration isn't a postulate, then you can prove it. How do you prove it?

Comment: What deals curve fitting with my question?

Comment: "What are the false postulate and invalid argument you refer to?"  See my answer here:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/246727/presentism-doesnt-everything-exist-at-the-same-moment

Comment: I fixed the quotation markup, but I suspect that you still need to (a) correctly represent the math and (b) do a better job of indicating places where you elide some of the quoted material. You've been using this site long enough that other people shouldn't have to do this stuff for you any more. Good writing includes making clear use of standard typesetting conventions, and that included how you indicate quoted material.

Comment: Einstein's field equation is a postulate, for the same reason that Newton's $F=ma$ is a postulate.

Comment: @ Pentcho Valev I like very much your demonstration of the clock postulate. BTW, who are the *Einsteinians* you are talking about with such respect? Are they a category of brainless people you do not belong to?

Comment: "BTW, who are the Einsteinians you are talking about with such respect? Are they a category of brainless people you do not belong to?"  Here are a few typical Einsteinians:  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BuxFXHircaI

Comment: @ Pentcho Valev : excellent! BTW, you didn't answer my question regarding the clock postulate, that was a serious question, I would be interested by your point of view.

Comment: Uh..."Einsteinians"? People like Michio Kaku, Brian Cox, Neil deGrasse Tyson, Brian Greene and Lisa Randall? You mean "physicists"?